# VS Code - HTML - Emmett Intellisense doesn't seem to be working as expected

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, intellisense, emmet

I'm attempting to learn web development, and I'm taking an online course from udemy. I am still in the html coding stage and I don't get the correct attributes auto suggested when I type in "form" (without the quotes). I get this:

When the instructor does it, this is the result:

I'm certain I used to get the result the instructor got, but I don't now. I rolled back to version 1.33 of VS Code but that didn't help.

Any suggestions? I appreciate any and all help you can provide but please don't assume I can navigate to whatever setting needs to be changed Please provide the full path to allow me to get there! Thanks again.

Comment: Please update your question. Seems like you missed something.

Comment: I typed in the html code with brackets and that didn't appear in my question. how can i show that?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do

Comment: did you check [VSCode official docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/emmet) ?

Comment: Thank you demkovych. Unfortunately I can't post another question for 90 minutes.

Comment: I just checked the docs at the link you provided, but it appears that this relates to Emmet abbreviations. My issue is that I'm not getting all the Attributes listed when I type in the "form" tag. I may be mistaken and this is not an Emmet or Intellisense issue.

Comment: how do you expected to view them? You need to put form tag first and then start typing some form attribute.

Comment: https://monosnap.com/file/ugYIeWjOCWS619zRKzVBt5bfu2dRl9

Comment: I did put the form tag in (without brackets) and then hit tab. I normally would have got all the attributes, but now I'm only getting the action="" attribute

Comment: The instructor did not type any additional attributes yet she got 2 additional ones class and action. Sorry, but what does monosnap do?

Comment: It does screenshots

Comment: Oops sorry she got method as well as action and class

Comment: Can I add the screenshot to these comments

Comment: he wrote `form.test` and pressed `tab` and it transform into `<form class="test">`

Comment: Here is useful cheatsheet for emmet https://docs.emmet.io/cheat-sheet/

Comment: No she wrote form, then hit either tab or enter and got all the attributes (class, action and method). Uh Oh, I just realized something. For some reason she is using Atom not VS Code as her text editor. Could that be the reason why she is getting different results?

Comment: No, she is using custom emmet settings, where she changed default abbreviations for form element

Comment: You can do it like `form:get.test` and you will get form with class test and method get

Comment: Really appreciate the link for the cheatsheet. Downloaded and saved it.

Comment: Where do I type in form;get.test Sorry, but I am really new to this. And how are you making the code look like code?

Comment: And she actually said "these are the default attributes for form".

Comment: And i apologize for this extended comment discussion, but as I'm new I can't switch over to chat. Not enough reputation.

Comment: After this my reputation will be so bad that Google won't even allow me to come here!

Comment: So I typed the code you gave me into my html file and got the expected results, However, I certain that I used to get the same results without without typing in the typing in the :get.test part. And the instructor did not do that. I need to figure out how to make that a snippet

Answer (score 0):

So I just downloaded and installed Atom. When you type form and hit tab you get three attributes: class, action and method. I wonder why the defaults are different between the two editors. I prefer VS Code just for the visual appearance of it, and it seems to be the one everyone uses, but why the difference and is there a way to make them the same?